# JQM - trigger('create') not applying styles

Tags: jquery, mobile, radio-button

Im a newbie at JQM. I'm having some problems with adding radio-buttons while looping trough a json object. The problem is that when trigger('create') is run on the controlgroup, the controlgroup stays empty.

DEMO : http://m.dzemo.se/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Visning</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" id="content">   
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-holder left">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="visning-dates">
                <h2>Visning:</h2>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="form-holder left border-left">
            <h2>Plats</h2>
            <img src="img/map.png" class="map" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-holder left">
            <div class="input-holder">
                <label for="firstname">Förnamn:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-holder">
                <label for="phone">Telefon:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" />    
            </div>          
        </div>

        <div class="form-holder left border-left">
            <div class="input-holder">
                <label for="lastname">Efternamn:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-holder">
                <label for="email">Epost:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />    
            </div>

            <div class="input-holder">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-theme="b" value="Skicka" />    
            </div>      
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    Lite content.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
var dates = {
    "date" : [
        {
            'day' : 24,
            'month' : 'Oktober',
            'year' : 2012
        },
        {
            'day' : 1,
            'month' : 'Januari',
            'year' : 2013
        }
    ]
};

$.each( dates, function( index, value ){

    $.each( dates[index], function( i, val) {
        var data = '<input type="radio" name="radio-visnings-date" value="' + this.day + ' ' + this.month + ' ' + this.year + '"/><label for="radio-visnings-date">' + this.day + ' ' + this.month + ' ' + this.year + '</label>';

        $('#visning-dates').append( data ).trigger('create');
    });

});
```

});

I have checked so that data is right with console.log and the result looks like expecting but i just dont get any elements on the page.

EDIT:
Changed the Javascript to:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
var dates = {
    "date" : [
        {
            'day' : 24,
            'month' : 'Oktober',
            'year' : 2012
        },
        {
            'day' : 1,
            'month' : 'Januari',
            'year' : 2013
        }
    ]
};

var data = '';
$.each( dates, function( index, value ){

    $.each( dates[index], function( i, val) {
        data += '<input type="radio" name="radio-visnings-date" value="' + this.day + ' ' + this.month + ' ' + this.year + '"/><label for="radio-visnings-date">' + this.day + ' ' + this.month + ' ' + this.year + '</label>';

    });

});

$('#visning-dates').append( data ).trigger('create');
$('#visning-dates').controlgroup('refresh');
```

});

I now get the elements in the DOM but no jqm basic styles. :/

Comment: Has the expected output if you do "alert(data);" before $('#visning-dates').append(...  ?

Comment: I ran a console.log on data and the output looks right.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the radio buttons element is not in the DOM to start with so the JQM css does not get applied to it, I encountered a similar problem when trying to add a dropdown box dynamically to my page a few weeks ago.

The way I solved it was to create an empty element (in your case a radio buttons set) and hide it, then simply append the data, refresh the element and then show it. there will be no need for the 'create' method.. so...

```
<input type="radio"  id="radio-visnings-date"/>
```

should be in your html from the start, this way the JQM styles are applied to it..

then in your js the following should be used to hide the radio element on pageload:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#visning-dates').hide(); 
});
```

then replace

```
$('#visning-dates').append( data ).trigger('create');
 $('#visning-dates').controlgroup('refresh');
```

with

```
$('#visning-dates').append( data );
$('#visning-dates').controlgroup('refresh', true);
$('#visning-dates').show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the formatting looks better now but still no styles like the regular radio-buttons. Can't figure out why it isn't working!

Comment: Ok now I am not sure what you are trying to do, can you be a bit more descriptive about what you want, and what you currently have...

Comment: Ok, I can try. I'm going to get dates with Ajax for the radio-buttons on the page (http://m.dzemo.se). I can add the new radio-buttons through JS but they dont get the basic radio-button styles that come with JQM but the markup looks right in the DOM after appended.

Comment: I've just had a poke about on your page, it looks like you are not appending the 'data' to the hidden element, you are still creating a new element. make sure the id of the initial hidden element is the same as the one you are using in your JQuery. In the code i supplied above, replace #visning-dates with the id of the empty hidden radio input

Comment: I've done the changes you mentioned, I get the radio-buttons in the DOM and they do display but they are still not getting the right styles..

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
```

and enclose it in

```
$(function() {
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Yrxqr/)

Comment: That did not help. Still nog getting no styles on the elements.

Comment: The each loop seems to be fine.. Just modify the pageinit event and add the DOM Ready Handler

Comment: But am i not supposed to use bind('pageinit') in JQM istead of $(document).ready like in jQuery? All other styles work just no the ones on the dynamicly added radio buttons.

Comment: Just like in the DEMO above, i get the radio-buttons in the dom and can "use" them, but im still not getting the basic style of Jquery Mobile on the radio-buttons. Like the classes are not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a class on all the radio buttons, then try the following:

```
$('.radiosclass').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: Added a class (.radio-buttons) but get the error: Uncaught cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/applying-styles-to-dynamically-added-radio-buttons

Comment: I don't know what im doing wrong, i followed the instructions but it's still just coming out without styles.

Comment: $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio('refresh'); - makes the positioning a little better but still not getting the desired style.